# How do you populate a JTable with data from a different JFrame in eclipse

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Okay the problem is I created a main frame which is supposed to capture the information added from the second frame. I have tested it in one frame and it works fine but when separated it doesn't.

this is the table format in the mainframe.

```
table = new JTable();
        table.setBounds(10, 11, 394, 182);
        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        Object[] column = {"ID","Name","Budget","Ministry"};
        Object[] row = new Object[0];
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(column);
        table.setModel(model);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

this is the code I add written for the second frame:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Register");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                
                PromoterView mde = new PromoterView();
                row[0]=i.getText();
                row[1]=n.getText();
                row[2]=b.getText();
                row[3]=m.getText();
                row[4]=a.getText();
                mde.model.addRow(PromoterView.row);
    }
```

the problem is getting the register button link and populate the Jtable.

Comment: If if doesn't work in the child window then you don't have proper reference to the TableModel. You should NOT reference the model by variable name. You should have a getter method to access the table.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)